# Display ongoing position of a point along put beside boxplots

Tags: r, boxplot

Suppose to have a list of lists:

```
list1<-list(a=20,b=30,c=12,d=15,e=20,f=2,g=8,h=0,l=3,z=22)
list2<-list(c=80,d=20,l=2,m=4,n=3,p=12,q=10,r=15,s=15,z=2)
list3<-list(a=9,b=8,d=4,e=3,f=4,g=5,s=8,t=23,u=20)
list4<-list(b=12,c=91,d=4,e=4,f=5,g=23,h=12,r=2,u=12)
```

I want to display a plot with 4 boxplots one beside another, referring each to one of those 4 lists labelling each boxplot for example with names "list1", "list2", "list3", "list4".

On adding, what about If I want to highlight the ongoing position of a point named "c" in the lists along the boxplots of the 4 distributions, provided that "c" might exist or not in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of lists like so:

```
# list of lists
listlist <- list(list1=list1, list2=list2, list3=list3, list4=list4)
```

You can use the following code:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,4)) # setup figure
lapply(names(listlist), function(i) {
  boxplot(unlist(listlist[i]), ylim = c(0, 100), main = i) # boxplots
  points(unlist(listlist[[i]]["c"]), col = "red", cex = 5) # "c" observations
  })
```

[image]

Note that if you have more than one observation "c" per list, then you need to change the code a bit:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,4)) # setup figure
lapply(names(listlist), function(i) {
  boxplot(unlist(listlist[i]), ylim = c(0, 100), main = i)
  points(y = unlist(listlist[[i]])[names(unlist(listlist[[i]])) == "c"], 
         x = rep(1, sum(names(unlist(listlist[[i]])) == "c")),  
         col = "red", cex = 5) 
  })
```

Comment: Great this the answer.